# Passing an external parameter from a jsp to an xsl (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, xslt

Setting the scene:
I'm working on a webapp in Eclipse, with a bunch of JSPs and XSLs. And I need to hide some features depending on some users' attributes. This is the third job in the series.

For the previous 2 jobs, I was able to achieve my goals because either the required changes were on JSPs (straightforward) or on XSLs for which the objects existed.

I.e. We have the following sequence:
- searchForm.jsp (a form with some criteria you set up and submit),
- resultsList.jsp (a list of search results - clicking on any result brings the full record for the result),
- displayItem.jsp (the full record),
- record.xsl (the xsl that transforms displayItem.jsp).

Thus for the 2 previous jobs, the features I needed to hide were either on these JSPs themselves or on the xsl, in which case the (relevant) JSPs had:

```
<c:set target="${item}" property="xsltParameter" value="xxxx=Y"/>
```

where 'item' is an existing object and 'xxxx' a (usually but not necessarily global) parameter defined in the xsl.
For example:

```
<xsl:param name="xxxx">N</xsl:param>
```

Thus, if my changes were on the xsl, I would reuse the 'item' object to pass on my parameter and process it in the XSL(s).
E.g. I'd put on the jsp:

```
<c:set target="${item}" property="xsltParameter" value="abcd=AAA"/>
```

and add to the xsl:

```
 <xsl:param name="abcd"></xsl:param>
```

This way I was able to pass my own parameters to the xsl.

For this last job however:
- The XSL (filters.xsl) is quite short and self-contained.
- It appears on the same page as resultsList.jsp, (therefore after searchForm.jsp) but has no connection I can see with it.
- On the JSPs, there's NO (appropriate) target object I can (re)use.
- I've already tried on a/the JSP the way I know to create variables/parameters:

```
<c:set var="xyz" value="${abcd}"/>
```

but this doesn't seem to work (when I create a corresponding xyz global parameter in filters.xsl).

My issues are:
- I'm struggling to create an object (if that's what I need to do).
- I may need to do something else, but I'm not sure what (hence my post).

Plan B
In desperation, with plan B I'm creating as a proof-of-concept, a static xml file (param-val.xml), in the same location as the XSLs, in which I put my external parameter/criterion:

```
 <paramroot>
   <paramval>abcd</paramval>
 </paramroot>
```

What I'd like to do is using the document() function, extract this parameter and use it either within filters.xsl if possible or otherwise a go-between prefilters.xsl that filters.xsl would import.  And this is where I'd need some help/tips/etc.

```
<xsl:param name="theXML" select="'prefilters.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="myDoc" select="document($theXML)" />
```

I've been reading stuff on the web and tested a few things, but I'm stuck (rusty on some topics and learning others).  How can I grab and use the 'abcd' in either filters or prefilters?

Any suggestions on how best to handle this?

Sorry for the lenghty post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks and regards.

Comment: Not very clear to me what you have so far. Please post the excerpt from the JSP where you call the XSL.

Comment: I have 2 separate scenarios.

Comment: Scenario 1: JSP: <c:set var="normalaccount" value="${sessionScope.nogeoparam}" />   XSL: <xsl:param name="normalaccount" />      Scenario 2: Please refer to my post.  I'm trying to get/use the value in the xml as a parameter.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't know **how** and **where** are you calling your XSL . I encourage to edit your post to provide more details.